# Ubuntu with all desktop environments

Tags: desktop-environments

I would like to have [all desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available), However it seems there should be conflicts between them, specially between the default application each of them use. My question is: is there anyway to install every DE without conflicting between them and run each of them smoothly?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? If you want to try out a few to see which one you like, simply make live USBs of them (or, even simpler, use them virtually from within your existing distro).

Comment: There can be different reasons. For instance a computer with multi user that gives each of them the choice of DE.

Comment: It is possible to install a lot of them without conflict, but KDE is imho the most problematic . I would recommend either avoiding this one or install kubuntu in virtual box